# Efficient Algorithm to Find Subset of Vectors Over $\mathbb{F}_q$ Living in Low Dimensional Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, computer-science

Let $q$ be a fixed prime, $P, Q$ be polynomials with $\mathrm{deg}(Q) < \mathrm{deg}(P)$ and $h = O(\log n)$.

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ of size $P(n)$ such that there exists a subset of $S$ of size $Q(n)$ that lives in a subspace of dimension $h$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Does there exists an efficient (randomized) algorithm that outputs a subset of $S$ of polynomial size that lives in a subspace of dimension $O(\log n)$?

This seems like it should be easy but I couldn't find anything.

There are some heuristics that seem to kind of work. For example, take a random vector $v$, and compute $\langle v , s \rangle$ for every $s \in S$. If you get $0$ with sufficiently high probability, remove all $s \in S$ that don't satisfy $\langle v, s \rangle = 0$ and repeat. Also, you can trivially get time like $n^{O(\log n)}$ by picking $h$ random vectors in $S$ and taking all elements of $S$ that are in the span of those.

Comment: cant u just output $\{0\}$?

Comment: I should have added that the output should be a set of non-constant polynomial size, so the set should be of size $\Omega(n)$.